# Measure to retrieve last value in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have that table in PowerBI

```
01/02/2016  1200
20/02/2016  500     <<- this
01/03/2016  700
03/03/2016  1000
08/03/2016  1200    <<- this
01/12/2016  100
15/12/2016  200
28/12/2016  800    <<- this
03/02/2017  700    <<- this
```

I would like to retrieve the last value of each month to make a line chart.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the last value for each month and then evaluate only on those days:

```
Last Value =
VAR LastDateOfMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( Table1[Date] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            CalendarTable[Date],
            STARTOFMONTH ( CalendarTable[Date] ),
            ENDOFMONTH ( CalendarTable[Date] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Value] ), Table1[Date] = LastDateOfMonth )
```